# How to create a REST API like Facebook using Express JS and MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I want to create a rest Api like Facebook. I know how to create post, delete, update, get routes. But I want to know how can I create something like Facebook. I'm talking about how Facebook show posts to their user. If you login to Facebook and go to your homepage you will see all the posts from your Facebook friends, pages you liked, groups that you are in and some suggested posts by Facebook. And they don't call all the posts at once. They call posts gradually. And also they don't show any previous posts that you already seen if there are no updates. It will be a great help if guys can answer this question. I am using React JS for front-end.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I'm afraid "How do I create Facebook" is *far* too broad to be meaningfully answered here.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kD1YokHMCHs

Answer (score 1):

Order the posts according to the time (newest first) and fetch certain number of posts initially, when the user has scrolled to the bottom fetch further older posts. When reloads then bring in any new posts that may have been added, for this you must track the latest post shown earlier and compare with it for any new post.
Also keep track of the last latest post the user has seen.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will keep what you said in my mind.